# Provision subscription in checkout.session.completed for first payment

Tags: stripe-payments

When I create a checkout session, I include the user_id in the metadata. This allows me to retrieve the user_id when `checkout.session.completed` event is fired which I will need in order to save the stripe customer id in the database for that user.

Is this the correct approach?

The issue I am having now, is that given this logic whenever the first payment is created I will need to provision the subscription in the `checkout.session.completed` event, future payments will be handled by `invoice.paid` event. This is because `invoice.paid` will can only recognise the user by customer id, which gets populated by `checkout.session.completed`.

Question:

- Is my approach for storing the customer id correct?
- How can I provision the subscription from the `checkout.session.completed` event for the first payment and then future payments are provisioned by `invoice.paid`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To provision and monitor a subscription, [Stripe recommends](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=checkout#provision-and-monitor) listening to three events: `checkout.session.completed`, `invoice.paid`, and `invoice.payment_failed`.

If you need a `user_id` to provision the subscription, then yes adding it on the Checkout Session metadata makes sense.

When you get the `invoice.paid` event you can retrieve the associated subscription with the [`subscription`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-subscription) property of the invoice. And then, if needed, you can find the Checkout Session for that subscription with the [list checkout sessions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list) endpoint and passing the subscription ID.